# Forcing Clang to link with C++ runtime

Tags: c++, c, macos, linker, clang

I have a project containing a mixture of C and C++ source. It currently builds with GCC on OS X. The project has bespoke build scripts which invoke the `gcc` command to compile both the C and C++ source, and separately invoke the linker.

I am now trying to get it building with Clang.

Invoking `clang` does compile the source files correctly; it distinguishes between `.c` and `.cpp` source files, and compiles for the appropriate language in each case. I have problems at link time, though. When the linker is invoked as `clang`, the C++ runtime libraries are not linked in, causing a build error due to missing symbols.

I can link successfully when I set `clang++` as the build tool, but this then causes compile-time errors and warnings; it really doesn't like compiling C source with the C++ compiler.

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
...
/usr/include/stdio.h:250:49: error: redefinition of parameter 'restrict'
```

**I have to specify a single tool for the build scripts to use as the compiler/linker**, so I need to do a simple substitution of `clang` in place of `gcc`.
Is there any way I can persuade `clang` (not `clang++`) to link with the C++ runtime libraries?

Options such as `-stdlib=libc++` don't work.

Comment: Why must you provide a single tool? The toolchain should be able to handle both a C and a C++ compiler

Comment: Custom build scripts which would be too painful to change to allow for separate tools.

Comment: Just inverse the relationship. Create a 'compile' script that takes the arguments, tests whether the file is C or C++ and calls clang or clang++ as needed. Update your build scripts to refer to that script. Alternatively, link always with clang++

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should just be able to use the normal linker flag, same as you'd do for gcc: `clang -lc++` or `clang -lstdc++` depending on which implementation you want. (and you should want libc++)

Comment: @H2CO3 `-lc++` is for libc++ and `-lstdc++` is for libstdc++.

Comment: Well, it was that simple. I get warnings about the `-lc++` flag being ignored when using the tool in compiler mode, but I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok both -lm & -lc++ fixed ARM32 & ARM64 builds for me in VS 2019 Android builds. Think there is a bug in VS which led me here.